# Page not found when trying to refresh page or access it through a link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm only able to access dynamic subpages ([www.sg.com/movie/43434](http://www.sg.com/movie/43434)) via click events. Once it's open and I try to refresh it, it gives a blank page or page not found error. Also if someone would try to access it via a shared link it also gives same error. I host it on Netlify. Could please someone tell me what should I change in my code for this to work ? I'm not using webpack and already tried HashRouter but it gave same error.

The index.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import persistedReducer from './reducers/index';

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

const persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And the App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
//Components
import GlobalStyles from './components/GlobalStyles';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import MovieDetail from './components/MovieDetail';
import Watchlist from './pages/Watchlist';
//Router
import { Switch, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const pathId = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
  return (
    <div className='App' style={{ overflowX: 'hidden' }}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/watchlist/movie/:id'>
          <MovieDetail pathId={pathId} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/watchlist'>
          <Watchlist />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/movie/:id'>
          <MovieDetail pathId={pathId} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Reducer file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import moviesReducer from './moviesReducer';
import detailReducer from './detailReducer';
import heroReducer from './heroReducer';
import watchlistReducer from './watchlistReducer';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  movies: moviesReducer,
  detail: detailReducer,
  hero: heroReducer,
  favorites: watchlistReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default persistedReducer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a config for your persistStore, like this

```
const persistConfig = { // configuration object for redux-persist
    key: 'root',
    storage, // define which storage to use
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer) // create a persisted reducer
```

Read more this https://dev.to/bhatvikrant/redux-persist-v6-in-detail-react-10nh

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it's already added in another file. I included that missing code.

Comment: Did you check your localStorage? Does It store your redux store duplicate?

Comment: I'm not sure where should I check, I'm quite new to this :)

Comment: DevTools -> Application-> In the left side find localStorage and  look at keys and values

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I see in DevTools

Comment: I think you need to have some preloder when your persistor rehydrates your store from localStorage. It should be some appReady flag inside redux store.

Redux-persist emits REHYDRATE action when, store was rehydrated, you need set appReady to true when REHYDRATE happens

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.